# Как отредактировать в коде шапку WordPress

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны

У меня следующая проблема. В WordPress чайник. Мне необходимо добавить в шапку WordPress (header) определённый текст, то есть отредактировать шапку. В админке нажимаю на "Внешний вид", но там только подпункты : Темы, Настроить, Меню. А вот "Редактировать" нет. Как же мне быть? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сильно зависит от темы. Попробуйте Внешний вид -> Настроить, или поискать в админке опции темы. Возможно, вообще придётся кодом вставлять ваш текст. Какая тема WP?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно посмотреть в настройках темы, либо в корне темы найти файл header.php и изменять через код.